# Vuejs setting reactive style to component in v-for with vuex data

Tags: vue.js, styles, vuex, v-for

Not sure how to work this...
I'm displaying table rows, pulling my data with vuex. The style changes, but is not updated in the browser. Only when I reload or re-create the component, it shows the style change. Scratching my head on this and what would be the best way to set a reactive style that is ternary based off the data loaded in the v-for component ?

```
<tr @click="rowClick(item)" v-for="(item, index) in List" :style="[item.completed ? { 'background-color': 'red' } : { 'background-color': 'blue' }]" :key="index">
```

item.completed is a bool

Comment: `style` is object, not array. `:style="{ backgroundColor: item.completed ? 'blue' : 'red' }"` will work.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I was able to correctly reflect what you were trying to accomplish. I used a `v-for` on the `template` tag and after that line you could access the `item.completed` boolean value. I had to use a `span` element inside the `tr` to apply the styling.

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      List: [ // comes from your vuex
        {
          name: 'one',
          completed: true,
        },
        {
          name: 'two',
          completed: false,
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
      rowClick(item) {
        console.log(item)
      }
    }
}).mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<table id="demo">
  <template v-for="(item, i) in List">
   <tr>
     <span @click="rowClick(item)" :style="item.completed ? { 'background-color': 'red' } : { 'background-color': 'blue' }">{{ i }}: {{ item.name }}</span>
    </tr>
  </template>
</table>
```

I think it could be solved a little bit cleaner. What do you think? Does it goes in the right direction?